# Force Flowplayer fullscreen on Internet Explorer [iframe]

Tags: internet-explorer, fullscreen, flowplayer

I've been testing Flowplayer and other media player on a site to see which one fits better the need. Flowplayer is doing the work pretty well, but with the little detail that the player won't give the option for fullscreen for Internet Explorer users. I've been looking around for a while, including here on SO, for an idea to solve this but not success at all.

To make it quick, right now I'm working everything out with a code that I got from "video for everybody", of course after getting the code I started modifying it for the need.

Here is the code that I'm using inside an iFrame:

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" poster="<?php echo $poster;?>" width="<?php echo $width;?>" height="<?php echo $height;?>">
<source src="<?php echo $video;?>" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="<?php echo $videowebm;?>" type="video/webm" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="<?php echo $width;?>" height="<?php echo $height;?>">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['<?php echo $poster;?>',{'url':'<?php echo $video;?>','autoPlay':false}]}" />
        <img alt="Big Buck Bunny" src="<?php echo $poster;?>" width="<?php echo $width;?>" height="<?php echo $height;?>" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>
</video>
```

As you can see, is not complicated at all to understand what's going on. I believe the issue exist on the fact that the player script is runing inside an iFrame whats limiting in someway the player itself of playing on fullscreen. I have tried many thing but no success with IE. Chrome and Firefox work like a charm, but IE just play the video with no Fullscreen Option.

I'm leaving an image so you can see what I'm talking about.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfnVo.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer doesn't support the full screen API [0]. The known issues list mentions:

"native fullscreen is supported in Chrome 15+, Safari 5.1+ and Firefox 14+ and others will use full browser window." [1]

[0] http://caniuse.com/fullscreen
[1] http://flowplayer.org/docs/known-issues.html

Comment: Very sad =/ guess I would have to find another player to work this out. Thanks a lot @dstorey